# How to delete sleep mysql connections which are created using a deamon program

Tags: mysql, pdo, daemon

While executing a daemon program it is creating around 10 connections which are in sleep mode.
We are connecting this using PDO library. This daemon will execute for every 1 minute.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: What issue? Why do you think something is not right? If the daemon needs connections - it creates them and uses them. If it decides to sleep and later continue using the connections - so it was designed that way.

Comment: I have around 50 daemons and it is showing 600+ are active connections. Actually we have around Max_used_connections 500.
So we are receiving "too many connections" issue. How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

See nice article from Percona guy http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/11/28/mysql-error-too-many-connections/

Long story short:

if you don't want to rewrite your daemons, feel free to tweak your MySQL by setting its **max_connections** to whatever high value required and see how the machine handles it (RAM issues might show up). But if most of the time the connections are in a sleep mode and your daemons do not cause high contention and deadlocks - you'll be fine.